# Write tests for a Java project that require Android environnement

Tags: java, android, sqlite, unit-testing, testing

I develop a framework for android platform, it's a jar file that generate source code when you put it in your lib folder of the android app, to simplify creation of SQLite DataBase.

The project is hosted in GitHub, and I want to write tests for this framework and use Travis or CloudBees for continuous integration.

I wondered how can i do this, the framework is a Java project that require an Android environnement to be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose http://robolectric.org/
may help you. But it will bring dependency to your framework. However it's only way I know to test android code without android.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might help me